# Executing CMD command C# (operation successful but doesn't do anything)

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file, cmd, registry

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = @"/K reg add ""HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer"" /V IconUnderline /T REG_DWORD /D 1 /F";

process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

If I run the program with admin privileges, it says:

> The operation completed successfully

The problem is that the registry key remains unchanged.

What did I do wrong? I tried to run a .bat, and it has the same problem. No errors, it just does not modify the registry key. If I run the .bat or the command in CMD, it works. If I try to run the CMD command or the .bat file (containing the command) from a program, it just says "The operation completed successfully." and does nothing. Thanks in advance.

With the registry class (no results):

```
        RegistryKey RegKey1 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer", true);
        RegKey1.SetValue("IconUnderline", 1, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        RegKey1.Close();
```

Comment: Why not use the [Registry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.Win32.Registry(v=vs.110).aspx) class instead?

Comment: Thanks, I will try and use that. Still, if I want to run a CMD command (not necessarily a registry edit), how can I do that?

Comment: Is it possible that you're hitting [Registry Redirection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)? E.g. affecting the 32-bit registry found under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node`?

Comment: I don't think so, it didn't change anything. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384253(v=vs.85).aspx                                     Also, I tried to change it with the registry class, maybe I'm doing something wrong again (edited the first post).

Comment: Nevermind, you are right, I changed the Wow6432Node keys. Thank you very much!

Comment: How can I target the registers found in the "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer". Both x86 and x64 builds only target the wow6432 ones. Thanks again.